# Get selected option ID from populated list

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a radiobutton list that is populated from MySQL. A function to be called when the selected radiobutton changes. I would like to be get the ID of the selected item.

```
 <ul id="radio" class="input-list">
<?php
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, "SELECT id, name, price FROM cases ORDER BY price");
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($case_id, $case_name, $case_price);
while($stmt->fetch()) {
echo '<li>
<input class="selectedoptions" id="'.$case_id.'" name="config-case" value="'.$case_price.'" type="radio" onchange="updateImage(this.id);">
<label class="sub-label" for="'.$case_id.'">'.$case_name.'         [£'.$case_price.']</label>
</li>';
}
$stmt->close();
>
</ul>
```

JS:

```
<script>

    function updateImage(caseid) {

        var selectmenuID = document.getElementById(caseid);
        console.log(selectmenuID);
    }

<script>
```

Attempting to get the id of the selected item is not successful. This is the console output:

```
<input class="selectedoptions" id="32" name="config-case" value="24"
type="radio" onchange="updateImage(this.id);">
```

I would like to get the 32 (the id). How can I do this? Thank you,

Comment: That looks like exactly what you've asked it to find. If you just want the id, then that is `caseid` in your JS function.

Comment: your script tag not formatted properly it has to be  <script></script> your closing script tag not right

Comment: @M. Tesrak check following link for id naming https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is right. The only fact about it is that you are logging in console the DOM element, not the parameter you recive `caseid` which value is the ID attribute of the element.

**Look at an example:**

```js
function updateImage(caseid) {
  var selectmenuID = document.getElementById(caseid);
  console.log(`Clicked on radio input with id:${caseid}`);
}
```

```html
<ul id="radio" class="input-list">

  <li>
    <input class="selectedoptions" id="1" name="config-case" value="'.$case_price.'" type="radio" onchange="updateImage(this.id);">
    <label class="sub-label" for="'.$case_id.'">Element with ID 1</label>
  </li>
  
  <li>
    <input class="selectedoptions" id="2" name="config-case" value="'.$case_price.'" type="radio" onchange="updateImage(this.id);">
    <label class="sub-label" for="'.$case_id.'">Element with ID 2</label>
  </li>
  
  <li>
    <input class="selectedoptions" id="3" name="config-case" value="'.$case_price.'" type="radio" onchange="updateImage(this.id);">
    <label class="sub-label" for="'.$case_id.'">Element with ID 3</label>
  </li>

</ul>

<input class="selectedoptions" id="32" name="config-case" value="24"
type="radio" onchange="updateImage(this.id);">
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe this is could help you:

```
<script>
    function updateImage(caseid) {

        const selectmenuID = document.getElementById(caseid);
        const id  = selectmenuID.options[e.selectmenuID].value;

        // console your answer
        console.log(id);
    }
<script>
```

This is the best way using javascript.